# Hibernate Criteria: How to reset projection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I need to select products based on tags, here are the tables

1. **products:** `productId`, name, description, price, etc
2. **tags:** `tagId`, name
3. **product_tags:** `productId`, `tagId`

   and I have 2 classes `Product` and `Tag` and relation is specified in `Product` class

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
   @JoinTable(
           name = "product_tags",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "productId"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tagId")
   )
   public List getTags() {
       return tags;
   }
   public void setTags(List tags) {
       this.tags = tags;
   }

**Please** note I only want to select products and not tags. following works fine

```
Criteria cri = getSession().createCriteria(Product.class);
cri.setFirstResult(index);
cri.setMaxResults(limit);
return cri.list();
```

As I am trying to get list for pagination, so I need total number of pages that can be retrieved by getting `totalRecords`/`recordPerPage`

```
Criteria cri = getSession().createCriteria(Product.class);
//add any required filter to criteria 
//e.g cri.add(Restrictions.like("name", keyword, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));

//********** Following code is in utility function ******************/
//Get total number of records matching criteria
cri.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
Long totalRecords = (Long)cri.uniqueResult(); 

//Get paginated records
cri.setProjection(null);// This is evil but works
cri.setFirstResult(index);
cri.setMaxResults(limit);
paginatedRecords = cri.list();
```

**Question 1:** Is it possible to set some thing like `cri.setProjection(Product.class)` instead of setting it null, I am aware that I can create a projection list and add all the column of product class but that seems overkill + the common part is in utility function and I found no way to retrieve the previous projection. `cri.getProject()`

Why I need another method because  `cri.setProjection(null)` fails when I apply join, because it will project all the column of products, tags, product_tags. which cannot be casted to List

Get all products that have associated tag ids as (4,5,6)

```
cri.createAlias("tags", "t");
cri.add(Restrictions.in("t.tagId", new Integer[]{4,5,6}));
```

Here is the issued query

```
select
        this_.productId as productId1_9_1_,
        this_.categoryId as category6_9_1_,
        this_.description as descript8_9_1_,
        this_.name as name13_9_1_,
        tags3_.productId as productId1_9_,
        t1_.tagId as tagId2_10_,
        t1_.tagId as tagId1_11_0_,
        t1_.name as name4_11_0_,
    from
        products this_ 
    inner join
        product_tags tags3_ 
            on this_.productId=tags3_.productId 
    inner join
        tags t1_ 
            on tags3_.tagId=t1_.tagId 
    where t1_.tagId in (4,5,6) limit 25
```

I have found a work-around for this as follows

```
cri.setProjection(null)
criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
```

This will fix type cast exception.

**Question 2:** The back-end query is still the same, it join and project all the columns of all involved tables. **((Yakkh dirty))**, Why the same query?, I am expecting projections on Product class only